# Applying Continuity to Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $(X,d_{X})$ and $(Y,d_{Y})$ be metric spaces. I am using the following definitions:

- A map $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is called continuous at a point $x\in X$ iff for every (not necessarily open) neighbourhood $V$ of $f(x)$ we have that the pre-image $f^{-1}(V)$ is a (not necessarily open) neighbourhood of $x$.
- The set $B_{\epsilon}(x):=\{y\in X\mid d(x,y)<\epsilon\}$ is called an open Ball about $x$.

I have already proved that $B_{\epsilon}(x)$ is a basis for a topology on $X$ and therefore open in the corresponding topological space. I have also proved that a set $A\subseteq X$ is open iff for all $x\in A$ there exists a $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $y\in X$ we have that $d(x,y)<\epsilon$ implies $y\in A$.

Now I am trying to prove that $f$ is continuous at a point $x_{0}\in X$ iff for every $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that for all $x\in X$ we have that $d_{X}(x,x_{0})\leq \delta$ implies $d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_{0})) \leq \epsilon$.

I have tried several approaches but failed every time so far. The most promising was probably the following: Since $B_{\epsilon}(x_{0})$ is a neighbourhood of $f(x_{0})$, its pre-image $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(x_{0}))$ *should* be a neighbourhood of $x_{0}$. Then I wanted to use the fact that a set $A\subseteq X$ is open iff for all $x\in A$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for all $y\in X$ we have that $d(x,y)<\delta$ implies $y\in A$. But for that I have to make sure $f^{-1}(B_{\epsilon}(x_{0})$ is indeed an open set. And even if I do, then it still needs to be shown that $d_{X}(x,x_{0})\leq \delta$ implies $d_{Y}(f(x),f(x_{0}))\leq \epsilon$. Also $\leq$ and $<$ are not the same and I couldn't come up with a solution to overcome this yet.

Maybe I should use another definition of continuity at a point? But then again, I have already tried other formulations of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B:=B_\varepsilon(f(X_0))$ is an open neighbourhood of $f(x_0)$ so the assumption tells us $f^{-1}[B]$ is a neighbourhood of $x_0$ so for some $\delta>0$, $B_\delta(x_0) \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$. Now show that this implies

$$\forall x \in X: d(x_0, x) < \delta \implies d(f(x), f(x_0))< \varepsilon$$

from the definitions.

Comment: Ok, so by definition $B_{\delta}(x_{0})=\{x\mid d(x_{0},x)<\delta\}$ and from $B_{\delta}(x_{0})\subseteq f^{-1}(B)$ we have that $f(B_{\delta}(x_{0}))\subseteq B$. 
Then I think we have $f(B_{\delta}(x_{0}))=\{f(x)\mid d(f(x_{0}), f(x))<\epsilon\}$ although I'm not quite sure how to justify this, especially the term $f(x_{0})$ on the right side of this.

Comment: @PAT remember what $B$ is. It’s really immediate.

Comment: Right, we have $B_{\epsilon}(f(x_{0})):=\{y\in Y\mid d(f(x_{0}),y)<\epsilon \}$, therefore $f(B_{\delta}(x_{0}))=\{f(x)\mid d(f(x_{0}),f(x))<\epsilon\}$ as claimed above.  And from this the implication follows immediately.

Thanks so much for your help, couldn't have done it without.

Comment: @PAT you’re welcome.